# Pandas dataframe has additional header after groupby agg

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have 2 dataframes that are 50 columns in the following format.

```
ID             v10    v9              GENE
NM_198317      0.0    9.666823e-01    KLHL17
NM_198317      -1.0   0.000000e+00    KLHL17
```

I wanted to average the values where GENE matched so I used

```
common_mouse = common_mouse.groupby(['GENE'], as_index=False).agg([np.average])
```

This has resulted in a table with two headers for each column, but I only want to preserve the older header.

```
logger.info("Column headers: %s" % list(common_mouse.columns.values))
```

Shows

```
[('v10', 'average'), ('v11', 'average'), ('v12', 'average')]
```

rather than

```
['v10', 'v11', 'v12']
```

I tried to use `zip(*common_mouse.columns.values)` in order to reassign the columns but I can't seem to get it to work. Is there a way to either prevent or remove the new 'average' field from the column header?

Comment: I don't get where `v11` is coming from.  But anyways, just use `common_mouse.groupby('GENE', as_index=False).agg('mean')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a list of functions as an argument for `agg`.  When you do this, you are telling Pandas groupby that there are several aggregating functions that should be calculated for each column.  It lets you know by creating a MultiIndex columns object.

So don't give it a list of functions to aggregate with.  Give it just one (not in a list).

### Use a scalar

```
common_mouse.groupby(['GENE'], as_index=False).agg(np.average)

     GENE  v10        v9
0  KLHL17 -0.5  0.483341
```

### String operator

However, Pandas has pre-coded strings that it has optimized algorithms for.  Averaging is one of them.  Use the `mean` string argument instead.

```
common_mouse.groupby(['GENE'], as_index=False).agg('mean')

     GENE  v10        v9
0  KLHL17 -0.5  0.483341
```

### groupby method

Even further, Pandas has a dedicated groupby method for this.

```
common_mouse.groupby(['GENE'], as_index=False).mean()

     GENE  v10        v9
0  KLHL17 -0.5  0.483341
```

Answer (score 1):

Reset index help you?

Like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
vetor = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['NM_198317','NM_198317'], 'v10':[0.0, -1.0], 'v9':[9.666823e-01, 0.000000e+00], 'GENE':['KLHL17', 'KLHL17']})


common_mouse = vetor.groupby(['GENE']).agg([np.average]).reset_index()

print(common_mouse)
```